# how to create a union type which describe all values from an array's field?

Tags: typescript

i have a function which accept an array and a field params, but i want to restrict field's type to an union type which describe array's all field value, like this:

```
interface item {
    name: string,
    value: number
}
const fn = (arr: item[], name: any) => {
    // if arr = [{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}]
    // don't want name have any type
    // i neeed name is a union type 'a' | 'b'
}
```

Maybe this need generic type, but i don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe this need generic type

Yes, exactly. You use a generic type parameter for the type of the `name` property, and another type parameter for the array elements that must have a `name` property, like this:

```typescript
const fn = <NameType, ElementType extends { name: NameType }>(
    arr: ElementType[],
    name: NameType
) => {
    // ...
};
```

Then this works, because they match:

```
fn([ { name: "a", value: 1 }, { name: "b", value: 2 }, ], "c");
```

...but this gives an error as desired, because they don't:

```
fn([ { name: "a", value: 1 }, { name: "b", value: 2 }, ], 42);
// Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'. (2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYB4BycMQAqAngA4oC8yAzmFKAOYA0yAanADYCuRZlyILhgBG0AHzIA3gChkcgfggAuZHgIlyAblnyAbpx4r23XlukBfaQgD2IWshghkVXIo0QWAUQ4QC4d8gQAB6QIAAm1FIKBCpqpijmYgAUOnJwUFAq3r4Q-nwA2gC6TKnRyqpufNIAlM4Skuba0gD0zcgA6tZQANbULKIIcFzUKAAGIIqjyBhwYAgAFhCRYIvIYHzI1jDI45PIoGur6VBwxIE+fmDU0o5J+VETMcgARHDPLPomKgCMyOYskjKKmewneyE+hmQACY-ixii8EM9qk1WshPBkusg4JEwktgFAIGF+hBBsMUMAwMgwtYliAAORgG4gO4PRTAt4fAzlX7-VlPEFgiHlGG8+EAFihyOkQA)

You've mentioned an `item` interface (idiomatically it would be `Item`, not `item`), but not used it in relation to `fn`, but **if** `arr` is supposed to be of `Item` elements, you can make `Item` generic and then use it instead of `{ name: NameType }` in the `extends`:

```typescript
interface Item<NameType = string, ValueType = number> {
    name: NameType;
    value: ValueType;
}
const fn = <NameType, ElementType extends Item<NameType>>(
    arr: ElementType[],
    name: NameType
) => {};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYB4BycMQAqAngA4oC8yAzmFKAOYA0yAanADYCuRZlyILhgBG0AHzIA3gChkcgfggAuZHgIlyAblnyAbpx4r23XlukBfaQgD2IWshghkVXIo0QWAUQ4QC4d8gQAB6QIAAm1GiYrup8YmIAFDpycFBQKt6+EP58ANoAukzJCgQqaqYQ0gCUzhKS5trSAPRNyADq1lAA1tQsoghwXNQoAAYgiiPIGHBgCAAWEJFgC8hgfMjWMMhjE8igqyupUHDEgT5+YNTSjgm5UiXKyABEcE8s+iYqAIzI5iySDxUT2Eb2QH0MyAATL8WIVnggnlVGi1kJ40p1kHBImFFsAoBAwn0IAMhihgGBkGFrIsQAByMDXEC3e7jUrPV7vAyPH5-FmKIEgzmfKEw5BwgAskKR0iAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `Item` generic.

```
interface Item<N> {
    name: N,
    value: number
}
```

And use it in the function declaration like this:

```
const fn = <T extends Item<N>, N extends string>(arr: T[], name: T["name"]) => {
    
}
```

When you call the function, `T[name]` will be the union of the `name` values.

```
fn([{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}], "a")
fn([{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}], "b")
fn([{name: 'a', value: 1}, {name: 'b', value: 2}], "c") // Error
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQLYB4ByA%20ZAbwChkzkQ4MIAuZHAGlPIDc4AbAV1os4wCNoxAL7FiCAPYgAzmGQwQyALzIsAFWQQAHpBAATaWky48Depp0R9h2VFABzPAAo4UKHTUBtALpnK1D08AIn8IIO8ASmUCEnJkETEFJ09CULoAcjh0szYuHgBGYTNUqh50-mzkXO46ACZhX2QguCCI4iSUtORMyuqCoqIu8t6OGuR6xqD%20VvaQZJKA7qyc0f7ioYqVvLqGsyCEVuQAeiPkAFE3CSggA)